# ASP.NET MVC Html.textbox - How to validate numbers only?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

With the HTML helper, how would you enforce number only without submitting?  I know it was done with regular expression if you had a textbox in classic ASP.NET

```
<%= Html.TextBox("txtYearOfWork",
                 String.Empty, 
                 new { maxlength = 4, size="5", autocomplete = "off" }) %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the data type on the model is numeric (int, etc) you can just use an attribute, and turn on client validation. [More details here.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use the [jquery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

This would allow you to just add the class "required digits" and it would do the validation magic for you.